# Limit number of <li> elements in <ol> and <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to limit number of `li` elements in `ol` and `ul` directly through html?

If I want to do it with javascript or jquery, how would I do it?

Comment: Limit them in what way?  If there are too many in the HTML to begin with, can't you just remove them?  It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: If you were interested in just hiding them via css, you can use [:nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) or [:nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: I agree with csum, use CSS to hide them, there're several ways to do that

Comment: Perhaps the more important aspect of this question has to do with where the `li` elements are coming from in the first place. Instead of going through rendering first before deletion, could you prevent them from rendering in the first place?

Comment: I use sortable from jquery between two lists so I want to limit number of dropped items dynamicly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery provides selectors that can simplify this process. For example, if you want to remove `li` elements at an index greater than 2:

`$('#myList li:gt(2)').remove();`

Or you can simply hide via css if you like:

```
#myList li:nth-of-type(1n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

Here's an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1sof7w0d/).

Answer (score 13):

You can do it with CSS 3, if you finally want to hide them.

```
li:nth-of-type(1n+15) {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use class and li element to hide li under class (this wont hide all li on your page but the one under the specified class).

`.class li:nth-of-type(1n+4) {
        display: none;
};`

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I knocked up quickly. My solution is just to hide the elements whose index exceeds some defined maximum - but you can use `remove()` just as easily. Take a look:

```js
var max = 2;
$('ul, ol').each(function(){
  $(this).find('li').each(function(index){
    if(index >= max) $(this).hide()
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to do this natively in HTML. But it's very easy to do so in JS or jQuery.

Hope this helps.